# Create entity for events in CRM 2011

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I built a web api using C# to communicate to CRM . I was successful to retrieve accounts. What I want to do is I want to retrieve the events from the CRM . I think I have to create entity for the events in the crm but how can I do that?

This is the code for the accounts

```
ColumnSet colsPrincipal = new ColumnSet("lastname", "firstname", "domainname", "systemuserid", "businessunitid");

 QueryExpression queryPrincipal = new QueryExpression();
 queryPrincipal.EntityName = "event";//systemuser
 queryPrincipal.ColumnSet = colsPrincipal;

 var myAccounts = CommonCrm.crmContext.RetrieveMultiple(queryPrincipal);
        foreach (var myEntity in myAccounts.Entities)
        {
            //create new crm users and add it to the list
            CrmUser thisOne = new CrmUser();

            thisOne.firstName = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("firstname");
            thisOne.lastName = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
            thisOne.userId = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<string>("domainname");
            thisOne.userGuid = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("systemuserid");
            thisOne.buId = myEntity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("businessunitid").Id;
            // and so on and so forth...         
            Console.Write(thisOne.firstName + "   " + thisOne.userGuid + "   " + thisOne.lastName);
            CrmUsers.Add(thisOne);
            arra.Add(thisOne.firstName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, via CRM Customizations and Solutions. As it is a pretty huge topic, I'd recommend you getting started with this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531186.aspx)

Comment: We already have events entity which is the default one comes with CRM but I can't find the way to point to like this way:
 queryPrincipal.EntityName = "//systemuser";